# Adding Action listener for buttons created by method

Tags: button, actionlistener

Ok if i have the following code:

```
protected void makebutton(String name){

         JButton button = new JButton(name);

         mypanel.add(button);
     }
```

then:

```
makebutton("Button1");
makebutton("Button2");
makebutton("Button3");
```

How can i add ActionListener to them. Which name do I use for ActionListener, tried many combination but no success.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is make the method return a Button. Thats way you can use the button variable else where in your program. What's happening in your case is that the button is encapsulated. so you can't access from anywhere else in your code.  Something like this

```
private JButton makeButton(String name){
    JButton button = new JButton(name);

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            // code action to perform
        }
    });
    return button;
}
```

You can use the method when you declare the button

```
JButton aButton = makeButton();
panel.add(aButton);
```

The more reasonable way to do it is just create the buttons without a method.

```
JButtton button = new JButton("Button");
panel.add(button);

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        // code action to perform
    }
});
```

I don't really see the need for a method.

Another option is to create a custom listener class

```
public class GUI {
    JButton button1;
    JButton button2;

    public GUI(){
        button1 = new JButton();
        button2 = new JButton();
        button1.addActionListner(new ButtonListener());
        button2.addActionListner(new ButtonListener());
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if (e.getSource() == button1){
                // do something
            } else if (e.getSource() == button2){
                // something
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Ok. Will it apply same action to all buttons or just one?

Comment: The first code, yes. Is that what you want? If not, then I would go with the second way.

Comment: I used a metehod because it is faster to add xy number of buttons. I know other example creating buttons and adding actionlistener to them. But if i create xy buttons with method, how can i add actionlistener to each, so it is different action for buttons, Or it is not possible and i have to do it the other way, button by button?

Comment: If you want a different action for each button, don't expect it to be a fast process. You still need to code the different actions.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void makebutton(String name){
    final String n = name;
    JButton button = new JButton(name);

    mypanel.add(button);
    button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            if(n=="Button1"){
                button1ActionListener();
            }else if(n=="Button2"){
                button2ActionListener();
            }
        }
    });
 }
```

you have to create more methods for every button.
I think peeskillet's second code is the good one.